# How can I save contacts on the SIM card alone by default?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, contacts, sim-card

Using ICS, is it possible to store and use all my contacts on SIM only?

If it is possible I don't really want to copy all my contacts to the phone and I would prefer all the new contacts to be stored only on SIM card.

Comment: Note, that while saving on the SIM, you can store far fewer entries and each entry would correspond to ONE number so multiple phone numbers for a single contact would still occupy multiple slots and capacity. Also, other fields like address, birthday, email etc. can't be used.

Comment: Yes, that's ok.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned which phone you use.

Unsure about ICS, but on Gingerbread, go to Contacts - press MENU > MORE > SETTINGS > SAVE CONTACTS to - SIM

This is available on newer versions though, YMMV.

Comment: I don't have such menu path... There is no "MENU > MORE > SETTINGS > SAVE CONTACTS to - SIM". I'm running 4.0.2.

Comment: Same here. No Settings menu at all. There are five options: "view group", "fast call", "accounts", "import/export" and "view profile" that all. No settings.